# Kudu table column containing created timestamp

Tags: ddl, apache-kudu

We are trying to create a kudu table that should contain a column holding the timestamp when the records are getting inserted.

We tried the below :

```
create table clcs.table_a (
         store_nbr string, 
         load_dttm timestamp default now(), 
         primary key ( store_nbr)
)
```

But the `load_dttm timestamp` is always the time when the table got created and NOT the time when records are getting inserted.

Any directions would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of Kudu as a database, which it is not. It is a storage layer. Drop the default from your Kudu DDL and instead use whatever function call is available in your SQL language processor that is performing the insert, such as `now()`, `current_timestamp()`, or `CURRENT_TIMESTMAP` (Impala, Impala, and Hive, respectively). Take note of whether the function call is deterministic (repeatable for the lifetime of the `INSERT` transaction) or not, depending on what time you want to record, the row or set of rows insert.

Comment: makes sense. we have used the suggested way to populate the date